# Assign attribute to first element of arry ngFor (angular)

Tags: javascript, angular

Okay so the problem I'm facing is I have an angular project and within that project I use the ngx-joyride library. now in my ngFor loop if you just assign the attributes in the code itself and run the tour (ngx-joyride) the highlighted elements are the last elements in the array and I wish to have it focus the first. I understand why this happens if we look at the code for the loop :

```
  <mat-expansion-panel class="site-item" joyrideStep="step1" title="Event sheets"
    text="This is an event sheet if you wish to run the complete tour please close the tour and expand the panel first"
    *ngFor="let sheet of eventSheets; first as isfirst" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
```

its because I assign the same attribute with the same values to all the elements so the as new elements comes through the attribute shifts one place till it hits the end.

how Can I ONLY assign it to the first element ?

images : 
This is what is currently happening : 
[image]

And this is where I want to be : 
[image]

Comment: Which attribute? `title`?

Comment: The joyrideStep, title and text haaha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<mat-expansion-panel class="site-item" [attr.joyrideStep]="i == 0? 'step1' : null"  [attr.title]="i == 0? 'Event sheets' : null" 
    *ngFor="let sheet of eventSheets; let i = index" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
```

Comment: you has also `*ngFor=let sheet of eventSheets;let first=first"` and `[attr.title]="first?'Event sheets':null"`

Comment: I tried this it failed but now I see where I made the mistake. thanks for showing me the way sensei.